# Kubernetes- error uploading crisocket: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I am trying to create a template for a Kubernetes cluster having 1 master and 2 worker nodes. I have installed all the pre-req software and have run the kubeadmn init on my master node. But when i try to run the kubeadmn join which i get as an output of the init command i am getting an error.

> ````sh
> [discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info
> from "https://10.31.2.33:6443" [discovery] Requesting info from
> "https://10.31.2.33:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned
> public key [discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid
> and TLS certificate validates against pinned roots, will use API
> Server "10.31.2.33:6443" [discovery] Successfully established
> connection with API Server "10.31.2.33:6443" [kubelet] Downloading
> configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.12" ConfigMap
> in the kube-system namespace [kubelet] Writing kubelet configuration
> to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" [kubelet] Writing kubelet
> environment file with flags to file
> "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env" [preflight] Activating the
> kubelet service [tlsbootstrap] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the
> TLS Bootstrap... [patchnode] Uploading the CRI Socket information
> "/var/run/dockershim.sock" to the Node API object "<workernode2>" as
> an annotation error uploading crisocket: timed out waiting for the
> condition```
> ````

I have done a swapoff -a before running this on the workdernode2

I was able to run the join once but after that, as a part of a script, I ran the kubeadmn reset followed by init and join few times where this has started showing up.

Not able to figure out what or where I am doing a mistake.

My main intent is to put all the commands in the form of a shell script (on master node) so that it can be run on a cluster to create a network.

Comment: You said that "i ran the kubeadmn reset followed by init and join few times". Could it be that you did not update token, generated by init and tried to join with not valid one?

Comment: No i ensured i used the updated token which i grabbed for the new init command that i ran. Also i realized that rerunning reset and init multiple times is corrupting the setup. If i try the script am using to create the template on a new machine it seems to goes fine.

Answer (score 17):

I had the encountered the following issue after node was rebooted:

```sh
[kubelet] Creating a ConfigMap "kubelet-config-1.13" in namespace kube-system with the configuration for the kubelets in the cluster
[patchnode] Uploading the CRI Socket information "/var/run/dockershim.sock" to the Node API object "k8smaster" as an annotation
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
error execution phase upload-config/kubelet: Error writing Crisocket information for the control-plane node: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Steps to get rid of this issue:

1. Check the hostname again, after reboot it might have changed.

   ```sh
   sudo vi /etc/hostname 
   sudo vi /etc/hosts
   ```
2. Perform the following clean-up actions

   Code:

   ```sh
   sudo kubeadm reset
   rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cni/

   systemctl daemon-reload

   systemctl restart kubelet

   sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -t nat -F && sudo iptables -t mangle -F && sudo iptables -X
   ```
3. Execute the init action with the special tag as below

   Code:

   ```sh
   sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=10.10.10.2 --ignore-preflight-errors=all
   ```

   (where 10.10.10.2 is the IP of master node and 192.168.0.0/16 is the private subnet assigned for Pods)

Comment: in my case master IP is 192.168.137.2 so should I use --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16  or let me know which one else to use ....note I am running master as Hyper V's Vm

Comment: I used root@POC-k8s-master:~# sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.10.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.137.2  --ignore-preflight-errors=all
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.16.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of validated versions: 19.03.5. Latest validated version: 18.09

Comment: Getting core dns pending .......
root@POC-k8s-master:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-7xk42                 0/1     Pending   0          91s
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-mbrlx                 0/1     Pending   0          91s
kube-system   etcd-poc-k8s-master                      1/1     Running   0          51s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-poc-k8s-master            1/1     Running   0          32s

Comment: ~# kubeadm config images pull
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.16.3
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.3.15-0
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.2
root@POC-k8s-master:~# export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
root@POC-k8s-master:~# sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1

Comment: root@POC-k8s-master:~# kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
serviceaccount/flannel created
configmap/kube-flannel-cfg created

Comment: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize

Comment: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Comment: "sudo kubeadm reset" and   "kubeadm init --config=kubeadm-config.yaml --upload-certs --ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU" works for me.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Removing cni config files helped a lot in debian bullseye `rm -rf /etc/cni/net.d/`
Probably had some old config from older attempts
My full reset command on the *master node*. **Please be careful this will destroy any configuration on your node.** `rm -rf /var/lib/etcd/* && kubeadm reset && rm -rf /etc/cni/net.d/`

Answer (score 9):

I’ve had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 amd64, fixed it with these commands:

```
swapoff -a    # will turn off the swap 
kubeadm reset
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X  # will reset iptables
```

Also, look at that issue in kubeadm GitHub [kubeadm swap on the related issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/610) where people still report having the problem after turning swap off.

You may also try to add *--fail-swap-on=false* flag in /etc/default/kubelet file, it didn't help in my case though.

It seems to be fixed in the latest k8 version because after upgrading the cluster, I haven't experienced the issue.

Comment: I skipped turning off the swap and the  `systemctl daemon-reload` bit as there is a long running job on the server and I didn't want to restart anything. Seems to work without it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend caution in altering iptables. This after enormous amount of troubleshooting on a 2 node Ubuntu 20.04 kubeadm cluster was down to internal node mapping that the CNI plugin is dependant on.

With `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname c23996dd402c.mylabserver.com` I changed the master node back to its mapped name and then did a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. I logged out and back in for good measure to ensure the reload worked. I could see the command prompt change back to the default VM node name.

The mapping now matches for hostname to private IP for the cluster:

```
~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
# Cloud Server Hostname mapping
172.31.xx.xxx   xxxxxxxx.mylabserver.com
woopsie@master:~$ cat /etc/hostname
xxxxxxxx.mylabserver.com
```

The worker1 node has the same problem so reverting to system default was the easier way for me. I just changed it `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname masterdefaultnodename`. IMHO, iptable alterations should be always done after careful consideration and as an escalated measure to fix the issue in my view.

Master done, onto worker1...

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                           STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
masterdefaultnodename.mylabserver.com   Ready      control-plane   33d   v1.25.0
worker1defautnodname.mylabserver.com   NotReady   <none>          33d   v1.25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

some commands provided need to run on all nodes like below.

```bash
kubeadm reset
swapoff -a => all nodes.
rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
systemctl restart kubelet
iptables -F
systemctl restart containerd
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then we need to run `kubeadm init` & follow the instructions given in the output.