# kube init: Error writing Crisocket information for the control-plane node: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes

I've tried many things to get it to work. I've disabled my proxy settings (removed all the environmental variables), tried with docker, containerd and crio. I've tried with   `serviceSubnet: "11.96.0.0/12"`, `authorization-mode: "None"`. Below are some related details and logs. Any help would be appreciated.

**Environment**:

```sh
ftps_proxy=http://proxy:3128
XDG_SESSION_ID=5
HOSTNAME=my-hostname
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
HISTSIZE=1000
SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT=1
USER=root
http_proxy=http://proxy:3128
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
SUDO_UID=68247485
ftp_proxy=http://proxy:3128
USERNAME=root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
https_proxy=http://proxy:3128
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
HOME=/root
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.3.11
no_proxy=***REDACTED****
LOGNAME=root
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
SUDO_GID=39999
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
_=/usr/bin/env
```

- **Kubernetes version** (use `kubectl version`):

```sh
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.5", GitCommit:"e6503f8d8f769ace2f338794c914a96fc335df0f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-26T03:45:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

- **Cloud provider or hardware configuration**:

from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```sh
processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8167M CPU @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 1995.315
cache size  : 16384 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves arat umip pku ospke md_clear
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 3990.63
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

- **OS** (e.g. from /etc/os-release):

```sh
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.8"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.8"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:8:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.8
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.8
```

- **Kernel** (e.g. `uname -a`):

```sh
Linux ********* REDACTED ********* 4.14.35-2020.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri May 15 12:40:03 PDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- **Others**:
  Output from `KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf kubectl get po -A` is `Unable to connect to the server: Forbidden`

Output from: `tail -n 100 /var/log/messages | grep kubelet` is:

```sh
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.245860   16845 eviction_manager.go:255] eviction manager: failed to get summary stats: failed to get node info: node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.268437   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.367850   16845 kubelet.go:2187] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.368580   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.468741   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.568945   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.669102   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.769265   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.869423   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:49 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:49.969613   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.069779   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.169952   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.270162   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.370314   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.470518   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.570690   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.670844   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.771025   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.871242   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:50 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:50.971404   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.071568   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.171749   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.271907   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.372112   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.472280   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.572449   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.672617   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.769715   16845 event.go:269] Unable to write event: 'Patch https://10.41.11.150:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events/my-host.161de4f886249d98: Forbidden' (may retry after sleeping)
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.772793   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.872998   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.911040   16845 controller.go:136] failed to ensure node lease exists, will retry in 7s, error: Get https://10.41.11.150:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/my-host?timeout=10s: Forbidden
Jul  2 02:31:51 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:51.973186   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:52 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:52.073314   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:52 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:52.173498   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:52 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:52.273690   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:52 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:52.373853   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
Jul  2 02:31:52 my-host kubelet: E0702 02:31:52.474005   16845 kubelet.go:2267] node "my-host" not found
```

### What happened?

I ran `kubeadm init` and got this instead:

```sh
kubeadm init --v=5

I0702 02:19:47.181576   16698 initconfiguration.go:103] detected and using CRI socket: /run/containerd/containerd.sock
I0702 02:19:47.181764   16698 interface.go:400] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I0702 02:19:47.181783   16698 interface.go:405] Default route transits interface "ens3"
I0702 02:19:47.181863   16698 interface.go:208] Interface ens3 is up
I0702 02:19:47.181909   16698 interface.go:256] Interface "ens3" has 1 addresses :[10.41.11.150/28].
I0702 02:19:47.181929   16698 interface.go:223] Checking addr  10.41.11.150/28.
I0702 02:19:47.181939   16698 interface.go:230] IP found 10.41.11.150
I0702 02:19:47.181949   16698 interface.go:262] Found valid IPv4 address 10.41.11.150 for interface "ens3".
I0702 02:19:47.181958   16698 interface.go:411] Found active IP 10.41.11.150
I0702 02:19:47.182015   16698 version.go:183] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
W0702 02:19:47.660545   16698 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.18.5
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
I0702 02:19:47.660897   16698 checks.go:577] validating Kubernetes and kubeadm version
I0702 02:19:47.660931   16698 checks.go:166] validating if the firewall is enabled and active
I0702 02:19:47.670323   16698 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 6443
I0702 02:19:47.670487   16698 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 10259
I0702 02:19:47.670518   16698 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 10257
I0702 02:19:47.670552   16698 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
I0702 02:19:47.670567   16698 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
I0702 02:19:47.670578   16698 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
I0702 02:19:47.670587   16698 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml
I0702 02:19:47.670597   16698 checks.go:432] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
I0702 02:19:47.670632   16698 checks.go:471] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0702 02:19:47.670654   16698 checks.go:471] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0702 02:19:47.670662   16698 checks.go:102] validating the container runtime
I0702 02:19:47.679912   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable crictl
I0702 02:19:47.679978   16698 checks.go:335] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
I0702 02:19:47.680030   16698 checks.go:335] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
I0702 02:19:47.680065   16698 checks.go:649] validating whether swap is enabled or not
I0702 02:19:47.680141   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable conntrack
I0702 02:19:47.680166   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ip
I0702 02:19:47.680190   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable iptables
I0702 02:19:47.680216   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable mount
I0702 02:19:47.680245   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable nsenter
I0702 02:19:47.680270   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ebtables
I0702 02:19:47.680292   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ethtool
I0702 02:19:47.680309   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable socat
I0702 02:19:47.680327   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable tc
I0702 02:19:47.680343   16698 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable touch
I0702 02:19:47.680365   16698 checks.go:520] running all checks
I0702 02:19:47.690210   16698 checks.go:406] checking whether the given node name is reachable using net.LookupHost
I0702 02:19:47.691000   16698 checks.go:618] validating kubelet version
I0702 02:19:47.754775   16698 checks.go:128] validating if the service is enabled and active
I0702 02:19:47.764254   16698 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 10250
I0702 02:19:47.764336   16698 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 2379
I0702 02:19:47.764386   16698 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 2380
I0702 02:19:47.764435   16698 checks.go:249] validating the existence and emptiness of directory /var/lib/etcd
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
I0702 02:19:47.772992   16698 checks.go:838] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.18.5
I0702 02:19:47.782489   16698 checks.go:838] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.18.5
I0702 02:19:47.790023   16698 checks.go:838] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.18.5
I0702 02:19:47.797925   16698 checks.go:838] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.18.5
I0702 02:19:47.805928   16698 checks.go:838] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
I0702 02:19:47.814148   16698 checks.go:838] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.3-0
I0702 02:19:47.821926   16698 checks.go:838] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7
I0702 02:19:47.821971   16698 kubelet.go:64] Stopping the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
I0702 02:19:47.952580   16698 certs.go:103] creating a new certificate authority for ca
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [my-host kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.41.11.150]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
I0702 02:19:48.880369   16698 certs.go:103] creating a new certificate authority for front-proxy-ca
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
I0702 02:19:49.372445   16698 certs.go:103] creating a new certificate authority for etcd-ca
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [my-host localhost] and IPs [10.41.11.150 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [my-host localhost] and IPs [10.41.11.150 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
I0702 02:19:50.467723   16698 certs.go:69] creating new public/private key files for signing service account users
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
I0702 02:19:50.617181   16698 kubeconfig.go:79] creating kubeconfig file for admin.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
I0702 02:19:50.763578   16698 kubeconfig.go:79] creating kubeconfig file for kubelet.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
I0702 02:19:51.169983   16698 kubeconfig.go:79] creating kubeconfig file for controller-manager.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
I0702 02:19:51.328280   16698 kubeconfig.go:79] creating kubeconfig file for scheduler.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
I0702 02:19:51.469999   16698 manifests.go:91] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
I0702 02:19:51.470375   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0702 02:19:51.470394   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-pki" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0702 02:19:51.470400   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0702 02:19:51.476683   16698 manifests.go:121] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-apiserver" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
I0702 02:19:51.476735   16698 manifests.go:91] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
W0702 02:19:51.476802   16698 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
I0702 02:19:51.477044   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0702 02:19:51.477062   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-pki" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0702 02:19:51.477068   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "flexvolume-dir" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0702 02:19:51.477095   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0702 02:19:51.477101   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0702 02:19:51.478030   16698 manifests.go:121] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-controller-manager" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
I0702 02:19:51.478061   16698 manifests.go:91] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
W0702 02:19:51.478146   16698 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
I0702 02:19:51.478368   16698 manifests.go:104] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-scheduler"
I0702 02:19:51.479022   16698 manifests.go:121] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-scheduler" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
I0702 02:19:51.479773   16698 local.go:72] [etcd] wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd member to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
I0702 02:19:51.479799   16698 waitcontrolplane.go:87] [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the API server to be healthy
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[apiclient] All control plane components are healthy after 14.502800 seconds
I0702 02:20:05.985260   16698 uploadconfig.go:108] [upload-config] Uploading the kubeadm ClusterConfiguration to a ConfigMap
[upload-config] Storing the configuration used in ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" in the "kube-system" Namespace
I0702 02:20:05.998189   16698 uploadconfig.go:122] [upload-config] Uploading the kubelet component config to a ConfigMap
[kubelet] Creating a ConfigMap "kubelet-config-1.18" in namespace kube-system with the configuration for the kubelets in the cluster
I0702 02:20:06.006321   16698 uploadconfig.go:127] [upload-config] Preserving the CRISocket information for the control-plane node
I0702 02:20:06.006340   16698 patchnode.go:30] [patchnode] Uploading the CRI Socket information "/run/containerd/containerd.sock" to the Node API object "my-host" as an annotation
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
timed out waiting for the condition
Error writing Crisocket information for the control-plane node
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runUploadKubeletConfig
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/uploadconfig.go:129
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:234
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:422
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.NewCmdInit.func1
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:147
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:826
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:914
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:864
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
error execution phase upload-config/kubelet
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:235
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:422
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.NewCmdInit.func1
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:147
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:826
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:914
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:864
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    /workspace/anago-v1.18.5-rc.1.1+d0eb837f519592/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
```

Comment: Did you disable the NodeLease feature in the kubelet  and the kube-apiserver ?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you may need to cleanup your node. The log file indicates that kubeadm cannot communicate to `etcd` which may be because of some existing iptables rules or hostnames not matching. You can try:

```sh
sudo swapoff -a 
sudo kubeadm reset
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -t nat -F && sudo iptables -t mangle -F && sudo iptables -X
```

And then re-run `kubeadm init`.

A similar issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55468054/2989261).

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it didn't work. I've turned iptables off completely (to make sure they weren't the issue) and the cni directory doesn't exist. I've already turned off swapping.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following scripts to completely remove an existing Kubernetes cluster, including running Docker containers

```
sudo kubeadm reset

sudo apt purge kubectl kubeadm kubelet kubernetes-cni -y
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -fr /etc/kubernetes/; sudo rm -fr ~/.kube/; sudo rm -fr /var/lib/etcd; sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cni/

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -t nat -F && sudo iptables -t mangle -F && sudo iptables -X

# remove all running docker containers
docker rm -f `docker ps -a | grep "k8s_" | awk '{print $1}'`
```